# Plot2DPanel- Set axis string labels

Tags: java, groovy, plot, javaplot

I am trying but not succeeding to replace numeric labels by string labels on a Plot2DPanel display.

Here is a look of my chart using numeric X axis labels:

[image: plot in a JFrame]

Here is the code I use:

```
    // create your PlotPanel (you can use it as a JPanel)
    Plot2DPanel plot = new Plot2DPanel();

    // add the histogram (50 slices) of x to the PlotPanel
    plot.addHistogramPlot("my plot", x);

    // put the PlotPanel in a JFrame like a JPanel
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("a plot panel");
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setContentPane(plot);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

I try to change axis labels by adding this line right before `frame.setContentPane(plot);`:

```
    plot.getAxis(0).setStringMap(legend);
```

Where legend is a `HashMap<String, Double>`, mapping string labels to position on the axis, but this don't change anything to the plot.

I can't figure what I am missing here. Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

kevinad

NB : If this is of any interest, I output this from a gremlin shell with groovy through X11 forwarding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set the legends you must use:

```
plot.setAxisLabels("Legend Y", "Legend X");
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Oh it's been a while since I stopped using Plot2DPanel, but the answer is legit ;)